# Node: Create panel to start stop node server

Tags: node.js

I want to create one panel having buttons start and stop which can user see (like html form with buttons) to start and stop **node server** rather than hitting command `nodemon index.js`.
 Also i want all the messages in the panel which are in command prompt that we console. Any idea how to achieve this? references would be more appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a second node server running just the stuff for this panel. Have your buttons ajax call a back-end action that just opens terminal and runs node start in the location of your app. You can then access the stdout via a pipe and then that pipe will receive any messages the terminal prints.

Comment: but for running that second node server again i need to go to cmd. Consider our user is not a technical person he dont know how to start server using command so i want the panel which just like html page opens when hit in browser and from that page he/she can start my node server

Comment: Sadly there's no way to call processes just from a static web-page. It's a security risk.  The best thing you can do is give him a .sh or .bat script that includes everything for startup and just tell him to click that.